# No account "admin" after attaching MySQL to Xwiki

Tags: mysql, xwiki

After following this steps:

http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/AdminGuide/InstallationMySQL

My XWiki became 'empty' (by empty i mean no pages, no permissions etc) which i think is normal. I found this extension:

http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Admin+Tools+Application

That I think will help me to manage my XWIKI. Unfortunetly in order to install it I have to login to my admin account, Admin/admin does not work. Any idea how i can install it? After connecting Xwiki to MySQL i lost all data's (probably including Admin account) - Did I do somethink wrong while following those steps? Should I somehow create admin account via MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled superadmin account in xwiki.cfg by uncommenting

> xwiki.superadminpassword=system

After login with `superadmin` account I was able to upload/restore all datas.